# Error creating a stage using Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I normally use the `deploy_revision` resource from chef. But I am checking out the Capistrano as i see a lot of folks suggesting it. My app doesn't involve any DB or any fancy things. The deploy just checkout the code from the github and place it at a defined location on the server.

I followed the github capistrano documentation (https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) & installed the ruby gem. Then, did this

```
bundle exec cap install
```

This created 2 environments : staging and production.

But i want 4 of them, so i did this:

```
bundle exec cap install STAGES=dev, test
```

Its appears to me that capistrano doesn't like the word test/testing. I can create with any other name except for the 'test%'

Is this the way - how capistrano works? Below is the console output:

```
[root@localhost testapp1]# bundle exec cap install STAGES=dev, testing
mkdir -p config/deploy
[skip] config/deploy.rb already exists
create config/deploy/dev.rb
mkdir -p lib/capistrano/tasks
[skip] Capfile already exists
Capified
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'testing'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
[root@localhost testapp1]# bundle exec cap install STAGES=dev, test
mkdir -p config/deploy
[skip] config/deploy.rb already exists
[skip] config/deploy/dev.rb already exists
mkdir -p lib/capistrano/tasks
[skip] Capfile already exists
Capified
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'test'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: `bundle exec cap install STAGES=dev,test` works perfectly fine for me, and it generates the `config/deploy/test.rb` file for me. What error message are you getting?

Comment: it was a syntax error :(  i inserted an extra space after the comma like this (after the comma).  bundle exec cap install STAGES=dev, test                            This is the post to the capistrano google group..   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/capistrano/IV-9OtVvLvE

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this question deserves to be here or not. But since i posted as a question, i am going to leave it unless someone suggest to delete it. The cause of the issue was an extra space after the , (comma). The correct syntax is

```
bundle exec cap install STAGES=dev,test
```

and not

```
bundle exec cap install STAGES=dev, test
```